# Magento2 Go to Checkout redirects to Cart page

Tags: magento2, onestepcheckout

We are facing a strange issue where **Go to checkout** redirects me to the cart page instead of the checkout page. This doesn't happen in all cases only sometimes, how am I suppose to debug this strange issue? Any guidance will be really appreciated.

Also, would like to know

1. Go to xyz.com/checkout --> it will redirect to /checkout/cart
2. Do Add a product from any pages
3. From mini-cart Go To Checkout -> it will redirect to /checkout/cart

=> Is this a normal behavior? what could be the reason for it?

Comment: which Magento version are you use?. Also please clarify, are you used any custom module or extension?.

Comment: It's magento v2.3.2